# prevent user from replying to email, @noreply?

Tags: php, email

I'm using the wordpress theme classipress and i've installed the plugin easysignup.  The plugin works but the problem is once the user has received the email, they can reply.  When i sign up to emails, they normally have a way to prevent the user from replying.

How do i accomplish this?

Do i have to create a @noreply email and change a setting so replies are bounced back?

This plugin required me to type in an Automated Reply Email, i used the website contact address just to test if the plugin worked.

Is there a host email address that is outgoing only?

Comment: You can't make it so users can't reply - that is up to their client. All you can do is send it from another email address and discard the emails it receives.

Comment: ok thx, i'll create noreply@website.com

Comment: I posted it as an answer so you can accept it. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about email administration, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make it so users can't reply - that is up to their client. All you can do is send it from another email address and discard the emails it receives.